# how to set cell width dynamically when exproting PDF using itext Sharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I Am Trying To Export data from database To PDF File i am getting but in PDF Cell Size is Not Incresing it is not arrange in correct format i.e cell is coming same width for all colouman My code is like this

```
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT

            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns

                'If column.ColumnName = "INVESTIGATION" Then
                '    Dim pdfpcell As New PdfPCell()
                '    pdfpcell.Width = 10.0F
                'End If

                pdfTable.AddCell(FormatHeaderPhrase(column.ColumnName))
            Next
            pdfTable.HeaderRows = 1
            ' this is the end of the table header
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                For Each cell As Object In row.ItemArray
                    'assume toString produces valid output
                    pdfTable.AddCell(FormatPhrase(cell.ToString()))
                Next
            Next
            pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
```

So My Question is How can i assign cell width Dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the width on the whole table

like this

```
Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {100F, 200F, 300F}
pdfTable.SetWidths(widths)
```

if you want one row to have a wider cell you have to use  cellspan

```
cell.Colspan = 3
```

Comment: But The Columns Are generated Dynamically